# What is the definition of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Cl}}(S,E)$?

Tags: clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

Let $V$ be an euclidean vector space, $\mathrm{Cl}$ its Clifford algebra, $S$ the spinor module and $E$ some Clifford module. The space $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Cl}}(S,E)$ appears both in proposition $3.27$ of [G] and remark $4.11$ in [R]. How is it defined? Do its elements super-commute or simply commute with the Clifford action? Please also justify your answer.

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, the most obvious interpretation would be that this as a special case of the notation $\mathrm{Hom}(M,N)$, where $M$ and $N$ are modules over the same ring (and hence that elements of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Cl}}(S,E)$ simply commute with the Clifford multiplication). My confusion arises from the following literature:

From page 104 of [G]:

> [image]

From page 107 of [Nicolaescu's notes](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/ind-thm.pdf):

> [image]

References

- [G] Berline-Getzler-Vergne, Heat Kernels and Dirac operators
- [R] Roe, Elliptic operators, topology and asymptotic methods

Comment: $\mathrm{Cl}$ is a ring and $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathrm{Cl}(S, E)$ is standard notation for $\mathrm{Cl}$-module morphisms between the $\mathrm{Cl}$-modules $S$ and $E$. How would "super-commute" make sense here? What would the degree of a map $S \to E$ be?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Thank you for your comment! I have added an addendum to my question, could you please have a look?

Comment: Proposition 2.2.6 of Nicolaescu's notes correspond's to [G] 3.27, and Nicolaescu's notation makes it clear that he is using the morphisms that supercommute with the Clifford action. For your question about the evaluation map, I am fairly certain it can work both commuting and supercommuting cases.